# How to make graphic inside another resize?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have placed a black rectangle inside a fluid puzzle image. When there is enough screen space it shows perfectly positioned where I want it.
When I shrink the window however, the puzzle image behind it resizes as expected while the rect inside does not. How do I position the rect relative to that of the outer image, and resize the inner image when the outer is?

This is what works while the screen is wide enough:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <img height="100%" width="100%" src="http://db.tt/hziXuB1a"/>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:58%; bottom:48%;">
        <a href="a.html"><img src="http://db.tt/27WmDZlc"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7t6C/27/

adding width and height for the inner image is not enough, as is for the outer 800x400 image.
The problem is that I don't use position:relative for it (as I do for the outer). This is the only way I know to specify the position as a percentage of the outer image ([relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)).

Comment: Half-done here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7t6C/37/

Answer (score 1):

Adding `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to your inner image will at least resize it.

```html
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%" src="http://db.tt/27WmDZlc">
```

It's also moving as it resizes, but I'm not sure where it's supposed to be in relation to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="puzzle" src="http://db.tt/hziXuB1a"/>
  <a id="link" href="a.html"><img src="http://db.tt/27WmDZlc"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
img#puzzle{
    width:100%;
}
a#link{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:58%;
    top:23%;
    right: 10%;
}
a#link img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/R7t6C/55/

Note:
`<style type="text/css"></style>` is not needed in the css-section of jsfiddle